# Android studio Geocoder get location category

Tags: java, android-studio, maps

I am using the Geocoder class in android studio and I am able to get country name and address by doing

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
        userCountry = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        userAddress = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
}
```

What I want to do now is to categorize the location.
Let`s say if I'm near a park I will translate the latitude and longitude to "park" or if I'm at the beach it will categorize the location as "beach".
Is there anything I can use to categorize these places automatically using longitude and latitude?

I thought maybe

```
addresses.get(0).getLocality()
```

but it just gives me city name

and when I tried

```
addresses.get(0).getFeatureName()
```

it just gives me a number so I'm not sure what that number is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your longitude and latitude along with Google Places API .

Through the API you will be able to tell if a user is near a city-based location such as a gym or a park.

You can find more information about this API [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro).

Comment: Does this API cost money or i didn't understand it right?

Comment: This should help you understand it a little bit better : 
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing

Answer (score 0):

Geocoder can't give you the types.

Also, geocoder isn't avaiable on all devices.

Instead, I would recommend to use the Google Geocoding API.

It returns types of places along with their names.
For more information, read here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: Note that Geocoding requires an API_KEY with mandatory billing.